# Factory functions efficiency

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-objects, factory, factory-pattern

I've been seeing examples of factory functions like this,

```
const dog = () => {
 const sound = 'woof'
 return {
  makeSound: () => console.log( sound )
 }
}

const poodle = dog()
poodle.makeSound() // woof
```

But this way, every dog created will have an extra makeSound function created in memory.
Wouldn't it be much better if the functions are external to the object created and just have the object be passed to the sound function like so?

```
const dog = () => {
 return {
  sound: 'woof'
 }
}

const makeSound = obj => console.log( obj.sound )

const poodle = dog()
makeSound( poodle ) // woof
```

What's the advantage of having the functions within each object created by the factory function vs having it outside and passing in the object you want to run the function with to it?

Comment: The disadvantage is that it is no longer an OOP method.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage is the **clarity for the developers** that `makeSound()` is something specific to `Dog`s.

Imagine you don't know the definition of the function.

The code :

```
makeSound(arg);
```

is valid with *any* argument in javascript. Or none, as it happens (then it will be just considered `undefined`).

Nothing prevents a developer from calling

```
const myUnrelatedObject = { foo: "bar" };
makeSound(myUnrelatedObject); // compiles and returns no error (will just print "undefined")
```

whereas the "object oriented" way will throw a **runtime error**

```
myUnrelatedObject.makeSound(); // TypeError: makeSound is not a function
```

Code good practices / patterns are made for human developers!

---

But you're right, there is an overhead. And that is the same for a lot of languages, when it comes to object-oriented patterns.

If this has actually a performance hit on *your* application, you can and should consider a trade-off between memory and readability (and thus, software maintenance cost).

But as a "default", I'll highly recommend (for you, your colleagues and your company) that you choose the path of the *readability* and *maintainability* first.

Also, keep in mind that you should really measure the performance impact in real situations. JavaScript compilers/engine nowadays can be very good at optimizing code, especially if it written in a usual, predictable way.

Comment: But before you use any functions, you'd either read the documentation or see how it was used previously, etc or have the function named as explicitly as possible. Like animalMakeSound(), would that fix the clarity issue? You wouldn't pass a table object into that.

Also, if it's external, if I have a cat making function, I don't have to duplicate it in the cat creation but still pass my new cats into makeSound. That feels favourable to me. It feels much easier to maintain too instead of having to modify all the factories later, having them externally makes it more flexible, no?